# How to acess (ping) VmWare Machine from host

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I have installed windows 7 on VM in my Windows 8 pc.
I am not able to ping my windows 7 machine (VM) from my Host (Windows 8).
I am using NAT network adapter. I tried using Bridged but it crashes my host (win 8).

I am able to ping from win 7 to win 8.

How can i make these two machines in same network and ping my win 7(vm) from host (win 8).

Please help

Comment: When your VM is configured with NAT adapter, it doesn't have its own IP address on the external network. Instead, a separate private network is created and an address is served by VMware virtual DHCP server.So usually, the network address that is assigned to the VM would be a [private network address][1]. 


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces

Answer (score 8):

Your problem probably comes from your firewall: Try to disable it on Windows 7 guest and you should be able to let it appear on host machine.

Comment: This helps me when I turned off both sides' firewalls.